# Redirect to random URL on each refresh in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to have an HTML or PHP script/page which will redirect me to a random URL on every reload I execute. Note that the URLs will be inserted by me manually.

Can we do it? and how?

Thanks

Comment: seems easy enough, what have you tried?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Do you mean every time you hit refresh (F5)? That won't be possible with *redirection*. Just randomly redirecting every time you open a specific page is no problem though, what problem do you have doing it?

Comment: Yes, you can do. Create array of url-s take one of it randomly and use [`header('location'.$selectedRandomUrl);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) `exit;` to redirect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the URLs in a MySQL database table you can use something like this to give you a random row:

```
SELECT url FROM links ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively if you have them stored in an array you can [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and grab the first element:

```
$urls = array( ... );
shuffle($urls);

// redirect to $url[0];
header('Location: ' . $urls[0]);
exit();
```

Comment: To avoid question: "how can I redirect to `$urls[0]`?" add that piece of code too. :)

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, you have typo `$urls` is defined. ;)